# Implementing simple logic and delay simulator

Tags: c++

I am implementing a simple logic and delay simulator. 
For this I have to make 2 classes namely node and wire, which model the netlist’s nodes (gates, in- and outputs) and the wires between the nodes, respectively. **A node object owns its output wires** – if a node object gets deleted, it deletes all its output wires as well. A wire connects two nodes and therefore stores a pointer for the driving node and the driven node, respectively.
Wire objects do not own nodes they connect – they don’t need to delete the nodes upon destruction. 
To test all of this I need to implement full adder.

Below is the program which I wrote.

```
using namespace std;

class node
{

public:
    bool a;
    //node();
    class wire
    {
         //Don't know what to declare here  
    }

};

bool evaluate (bool x, bool y, char o)
{
 bool z;
if (o == '&')
    z = x & y;
else if (o == '^')
    z = x ^ y;
else if (o == '|')
    z = x | y;
else
    cout << "Error" << endl;
return z;
}

bool evaluate (bool x) //Function overloading
{
 bool inv;
 inv = !x;
 return inv;
}

int main()
{
 vector<node> input(3);
 vector<node> output(2);
 vector<node> intermediate(4);
 cout << "Enter a, b and C_in \n";
 cin >> input[0].a;
 cin >> input[1].a;
 cin >> input[2].a;
 intermediate[0].a = evaluate(input[0].a, input[1].a, '^');
 intermediate[1].a = evaluate (input[2].a, intermediate[0].a, '^');
 output[0].a = intermediate[1].a;
 intermediate[2].a = evaluate(intermediate[0].a, input[2].a, '&');
 intermediate[3].a = evaluate(input[0].a, input[1].a, '&');
 output[1].a = evaluate(intermediate[2].a, intermediate[3].a, '|');
 cout << "Sum is "<< output[0].a<<endl;
 cout << "Carry out is "<< output[1].a << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Currently I able to achieve the full adder functionality but without using the other class wire. 
I need to include the other class in my solution as well.
How can I do that?

Comment: I do not get what is your question. Could you edit your post?

Comment: @AlainMerigot Is it fine now?

Comment: A wire is different concept from a node. Why is it declared within class node?  It should be a completely different class with methods maybe that update values along the nodes that the wire connects. Globally, your code do not use any OO facility of C++. You should really rethink your code, ask what are the kind of objects that you need to describe your problem, and implement them as true C++ classes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your nodes represent something that stores electricity (represented by the boolean) and connects to other node via wires, and when an evaluation between two nodes is done, the result should be sent to all the connected nodes. And you have implemented the node but not the wire.

You could add a method (lets call it `set_a`) to the `node` class that modifies its state (the boolean), and another method that tells each wire to call `set_a` on its connected node.

---

Update: Also, you would like to modify `evaluate` to work with nodes, instead of booleans. That way you have a more object oriented solution to your problem.

Comment: The connection should be something like this 
Node A --------wire------> Node B
      |
      |----------wire--------> Node C
One end of the wire should be driving node and the other should be driven node.
Like we have in logic gates, output of one gate being given to others.

Comment: Then, if the wire doesn't own the connected node, but a node owns one or more wires, maybe store a pointer to the connected node in each wire, and in each node have a vector (or similar) of wires.

Answer (score 0):

From your specification the structure seems like the following:

```
class Node
{
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Wire>> output;
    std::vector<Wire*> inputs;
};

class Wire
{
private:
    Node* from;
    Node* to;
};
```

In which all pointers are weak references except for outputs of a `Node` which holds the ownership on the attached `Wire` instances.

Since the structure is tightly coupled though you'd need to manage some aspects by yourself, for example:

- removing a `Wire` should clear both `from->output` and `to->input`
- removing a `Node` should loop its inputs and unbind them (so that the `Wire` is half attached, or if your requirement doesn't allow it, they should be removed entirely)
- removing a `Node` will invoke `Wire::~Wire()` on all its outputs which should clear all references to inputs from bound nodes.